# Comment voting and flagging UI not accessible on touch-screen

Tags: feature-request, user-interface

The Comment voting and flagging UI is not accessible from a touch-screen only device.  With more and more folks browsing with these sort of devices, it seems like SO needs to adapt the UI to meet the needs of these users.

Note: I'm not just talking about small screen phone devices here.  I'm talking about tablets that don't really need to use a mobile version of the site.

Comment: Both work just fine for me, from an iPad. What do you experience, and what are you using?

Comment: Are you talking about the mobile interface or the normal one? Lots of stuff seem to not be working or working awkwardly when browsing the normal interface with the Android browser...

Comment: @YannisRizos I'm referring to the normal interface that I've been using on the Samsung Win8 tablet I got at the BUILD conference last September.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the mobile site, one can vote, but one can't flag. (The mobile site is designed to be minimalistic, so I guess the omission of this feature is by design)

Using the desktop site on a tab (iPad), tapping somewhere on the comment makes the vote/flag controls appear. This should work for most tablets, they translate certain kinds of taps to `onmouseover` events (I think).

Using the desktop site on the Android Froyo browser (not on a tablet), I can tap to get the controls as well (though sometimes I need to tap hold/etc).

Which tablet are you using?

Comment: I'm using a Samsung tablet that Microsoft gave to BUILD 2011 attendees.  It is running Windows 8 Release Preview.  I can tap and hold the comment and *see* the up vote icon but I have yet to figure out a way to press that icon and have it work.

Comment: This option doesn't work with the ga release of windows 8 either

Comment: This option does not work on surface rt.

Comment: This doesn't work on win 8.1

Comment: Using modern IE 11 on Windows RT 8.1 (a Surface), tapping and holding for a bit on the comment does make the vote/flag UI appear. I can then pinch zoom in and activate either of the two icons. It would be nice, though, if a simple tap made nice touchable icons appear.