# Flagging and up-voting comments in not possible on the Surface tablet

Tags: feature-request, touch-screen

On desktop devices, the buttons to flag or like a comment appear when you hover over it.

However on my Surface, I cannot hover over it but I am on the desktop site, meaning I cannot flag or up vote comments.

Can this be changed?

Comment: Use the mobile version of the site (there's a link in the footer)? The desktop version is just plain not meant to work on mobile devices.

Comment: I can flag stuff on my iPad using the desktop version by tapping the area once, then tapping the icon once it comes up

Answer (score 1):

I have a Surface and I can do it by pressing down and *holding* anywhere in the comment (see red circle below for example location). Once I do this, then the icons appear (blue circle). At that point, pressing down on either icon will trigger the appropriate action.

[image: press-and-hold-to-show-icons]

Comment: This appears to work only on Windows 8.1 or newer, per [this comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174657/touch-friendly-comments#comment628106_174657)